# What is the best way to hide UIRefreshControl iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uirefreshcontrol

I have trouble hiding refreshControl once a user leaves the ViewController while refreshControl is still visible. I have tried setting it removing it from superView (tableView), replacing it with new one, etc... The issue still remains with tableView when user returns to the screen, top content insets remain from refreshControl before and it leaves a white space on top of tableView and if I do not replace/hide refreshControl, it will be visible at this point.

Any suggestions?

Image: [Transition between screens, refreshControl does not hide on viewDidDisappear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHolP.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have contacted a friend that gave a really nice answer. This was the code that helped me smoothly remove refreshControl in case it was stuck in frozen state on screen:

```
func forceHideRefreshControl(tableView: UITableView) {
    if tableView.contentOffset.y < 0 { // Move tableView to top
        tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint.zero, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Though if view controller hasn't finished loading, it won't have refreshControl visible. For that you'd need to call beginRefreshing() on it again, but I would do it with delay to avoid any animation problems. In any case, I think this was the best solution that actually removed the white spacing on top. I do not know why endRefreshing() did not work, but at least I found another way. Hope this helps anyone! :)

**NOTE:** However, this solution is tested on stuck/frozen refreshControl only. I do not know what effect it will have if you do not have this problem, but still use this solution for hiding refreshControl.

Answer (score 3):

Try this one :-

```
refreshControl.tintColor = .clear
```

Comment: if there are no any content or no any `tableViewCell` it will take space. It's default.

Comment: aye, the white space was the major problem. my friend had a fix! :)

Comment: how it will fix? Can you share the answer?

Comment: I posted my answer :) But I cannot mark it as an answer yet! :(

Comment: these comments are off topic - this answer worked well for me

Answer (score 1):

Initialize the refresh control:

```
lazy var refreshControl: UIRefreshControl = {
        let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
        refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: 
                     #selector(ViewController.handleRefresh(_:)), 
                     for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
        refreshControl.tintColor = UIColor.red

        return refreshControl
    }()
```

Handle the refresh and end the refreshing:

```
func handleRefresh(_ refreshControl: UIRefreshControl) {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        refreshControl.endRefreshing()
    }
```

Add the refresh control:

```
self.tableView.addSubview(self.refreshControl)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you present the new screen just use `.endRefreshing()` on your `refreshControl`.

Comment: Of course, that is the first thing I tried. This does nothing, I believe this to be iOS issue. RefreshControl loses refreshing state when user leaves viewController. If I call endRefreshing() in viewDidAppear nothing happens and if I check refreshControl?.isRefreshing, false will always be returned. (To be clear this only happens when you leave screen while refreshControl is still active / in refreshing state)

Comment: Can you show us some code, where are you calling the endRefreshing, how do you present the new screen and how do you dismiss that screen?

Comment: End refreshing: override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
    }

Comment: Presenting is whole other area. I use containerView for viewControllers and use them as pages. So ViewController goes into background with active refresh control and comes back with deactivated one, but still visible. (one of the VCs in TabViewController is pager, so it's large and a little complex)

Answer (score 0):

I've made it working for me by doing the following,
On ViewdidLoad I've made the

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    refreshControl.tintColor = .clear
}
```

and When calling the selector function I've used `refreshControl.endRefreshing()`
before calling my custom Loading function.

It's not showing the loading indicator for me.